# What color is the best gear?

Tags: the-division

I found some light color green gear. Like is that the best gear or something?

What color is the best gear?

Comment: If you're asking for specific items, we're going to end up closing this as opinion-based. If you're asking what the color means, which is what the first answer is telling you and what I suspect you're asking, then that's fine, but we'll want to rephrase the question.

Comment: ok yea i understand. Like is it the best gear color or is it the second best what i am trying to ask is it the best gear over all .

Answer (score 6):

The item categorizing goes in this order according to :

http://www.videogamer.com/features/game_guide/tom_clancys_the_division_guide_item_and_enemy_colour_codes_and_what_they_mean.html

White < Green < Blue < Purple < Yellow < Teal

> Yellow items in Tom Clancy's The Division
>
> Yellow items are 'high–end', and basically only dropped by bosses.
>   They're like the highest quality bits of kit ever. Worth selling your
>   entire family. That kind of thing.

The final color—teal—represent Gear Set items that were added in one of the patches and contain special abilities that stack with items from the same set. High End and Gear Set items are kind of on par with each other giving a trade-off of abilities.

Comment: Hey Kartyr, I just changed the symbols on your ordering there to less-than symbols. You had greater-than symbols, indicating white was better than the others.

Comment: Yeah, I'm always using less than to mean "You better go that way". It's better this way ^.^

Comment: Dont forget Cosmetics which are Cyan.

Comment: Ryan is that like paint jobs on your weapons those are the light blue color

Comment: @Robert__garnet The cyan cosmetic items are clothing and may include weapon skins if those actually drop that way. I think those are only available from vendors and as mission rewards that don't drop on the ground.

Comment: Cosmetics can also be blue, purple, and yellow. At least in patch 1.8; I believe patch 1.7 too. Also, you can generally go by gear score these days. Don't need to rely on color only.